# Как остановить проект PyCharm, что бы срабатывал atexit?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

**Предыстория**

Я написал чат бота, который при его запуске рассылает сообщения о начале своей работы, а при прекращении работы - о прекращении

Бот работает через LongPoll API, так что просто закрывать его через `ctrl+c` не удобно, может пройти большое время, пока `KeyboardInterrupt` долетит (25 секунд)

Запускаю я код через `shift+f10`, т.е. обычный запуск в PyCharm и останавливаю с помощью `ctrl+f2`

**Настройка atexit**

`atexit.register(self.api.tell_all, data=self.data, message='Бот выключен')`

**PyCharm**

При остановке PyCharm говорит, что завершил процесс с кодом -1, но `atexit` не срабатывает. Он срабатывает только если написать явно в коде `exit(КОД)`, ну или при получении эксепшена

**Вопрос**

Это я как-то не так настроил `atexit` и всё должно работать, либо это PyCharm так убивает процесс?

Хотелось бы иметь возможность останавливать бота со срабатыванием `atexit`, не ожидая 25 секунд каждый раз

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Остановка проекта через `Shift+F2` завершает скрипт, а не интерпритатор

`atexit` вызывается при закрытии интерпритатора

Можно попробовать блок

```
try: ... 
finally: ...
```